# Hive of amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive

I run a sql on aws hive.I use sum(column) but got sull,when I ran the sql again ,I got the correct result?If this is aws's bug or I operated imappropriately ?

Comment: I have used a table left join another table...Also I have tested  sum(column)=1 when column=null and   column=1

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not provided enough information to provide a useful answer. Can you please Edit your question to provide more details? For example, are you running Hive under Amazon EMR, or did you install it yourself on Amazon EC2? Is your data stored in HDFS or as an external table in Amazon S3. Can you provide more information about the data in your table and the query you used?